# Process Linq groups all at once

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

Suppose I have a custom object  with a public sub looking something along these lines:

```
Public Class MyObject
   Public Function ReturnData(StartDate as Date, InputData as List(of string)) As List(Of String)
End Class
```

And then have another custom object that looks like this:

```
Public Class HoldingObject
   Public MyDate as Date
   Public MyInfo as String
End Class
```

Now, in a different class, I have the following:

```
Dim DataList as List(of HoldingObject)
Dim WorkingClass as New MyObject

Datalist looking as follows:
MyDate:         MyInfo:
1/1/2012        a
1/2/2012        b
1/2/2012        c
1/2/2012        d
1/1/2012        e
1/2/2012        f
1/2/2012        g
1/2/2012        h
1/3/2012        i
1/3/2012        j
1/3/2012        k
1/1/2012        l
1/1/2012        m
```

---

What I would like to do, is make up some kind of a Linq statement that would:

1. Group `Datalist` list by date (Would be 3 grouped inputs - 1/1/2012; 1/2/2012; 1/3/2012)
2. Submit each group to `WorkingClass.ReturnData` as inputs and get the return value

How could I do this via Linq / Lambdas or any other way you see as being best programming practice??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I can't test it on my own right now, but it should work:

```
Dim result = (From i In DataList
             Group i By date = i.MyDate Into g
             Select WorkingClass.ReturnData(date, g.Select(Function(gi) gi.MyInfo).ToList())).ToList()
```

Comment: thank you so much!! - i'm 99% sure your solution works a charm, but now I've got a second problem coming about that I didn't mention in this question - I actually needed to group on 2 criteria (start and end date) - I thought this would be easy, but it's beating me - I posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940898/linq-group-by-errors If you have any input, that would be awesome!!! Nonetheless, your solution (once I get it working) looks perfect, I believe!! THANKS!!!!