# Linq Group By Errors

Tags: vb.net, linq

What am I doing wrong here?

I have the following object defined:

```
Public Class MyClass
    Public Var1 As String
    Public StartDate As Date
    Public EndDate As Date
End Class
```

And in my Main sub, I have:

```
Dim x as New List(Of MyClass)
```

Now, I want to group this such that all groups will have info that has matching start and end dates. I thought this should do it:

```
From Req In x
Group Req By strtdt = Req.StartDate, enddt = Req.EndDate Into grp
Select ...
```

Now, I have tried this in a few different ways and each time get different errors:

---

1)

```
From Req In x
Group Req By strtdt = Req.StartDate, enddt = Req.EndDate Into grp
Select ...
```

ERROR: `Definition of method 'grp' is not accessible in this context` (grp() underlined)

---

2)

```
From Req In x
Group Req By New With {strtdt = Req.StartDate, enddt = Req.EndDate} Into grp
Select ...
```

ERROR: `Type or 'With' expected` (First curly brackets underlined)

---

What am I doing wrong???

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ought to work:

```
    Dim y = From Req In x _
        Group Req By key = New With { .strtdt = Req.StartDate, .enddt = Req.EndDate } Into Group _
        Select Item = key, DateGroup = Group
```